# Variable overflow between instances in Java

Tags: java, variables, user-interface

I have a problem with my code, which is as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class mainGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 4149825008429377286L;

    public static Color black = new Color(0,0,0);
    static GridLayout cellLayout = new GridLayout(25,45,1,1);
    static  JPanel cellContainer = new JPanel(cellLayout);
    static JButton startButton = new JButton("Start");
    static JButton stopButton = new JButton("Stop");
    static JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    static mainCell[] cell = new mainCell[1125];
    Timer timer = new Timer(1000,this);

    public mainGUI(String title)
    {
        setTitle(title);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        startButton.addActionListener(this);
        startButton.setActionCommand("check");
        stopButton.addActionListener(this);
        stopButton.setActionCommand("stop");
        clearButton.addActionListener(this);
        clearButton.setActionCommand("clear");
        timer.setActionCommand("check");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        mainGUI GUI = new mainGUI("The Game of Life!");
        JPanel container = new JPanel();

        int xloc = 0;
        int yloc = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<=1124;i++)
        {
            mainCell childCell = new mainCell();
            cell[i] = childCell;
            childCell.setName(String.valueOf(i));
            System.out.println(childCell.isActivated());
            cellContainer.add(childCell);
            childCell.deactivate();
            childCell.setPos(xloc, yloc);
            xloc++;
            if(xloc==45)
            {
                xloc=0;
                yloc++;
            }
        }

        JPanel buttonContainer = new JPanel();
        Dimension buttonDimension = new Dimension(398,37);
        buttonContainer.setPreferredSize(buttonDimension);
        buttonContainer.add(startButton);
        buttonContainer.add(stopButton);
        buttonContainer.add(clearButton);

        BoxLayout containerLayout = new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
        container.setLayout(containerLayout);
        container.add(cellContainer);
        container.add(buttonContainer);
        GUI.add(container);
        GUI.pack();
        GUI.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("clear"))
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=1124;i++)
            {
                cell[i].deactivate();
            }
        }

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("start"))
        {
            timer.start();
        }

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("check"))
        {
            for(int i=0;i<=1124;i++)
            {
                /*if(checkNeighbor(i)==0||checkNeighbor(i)==1);
                {
                    cell[i].deactivate();
                }
                if(checkNeighbor(i)==2||checkNeighbor(i)==3);
                {
                    cell[i].activate();
                }
                if(checkNeighbor(i)>=4)
                {
                    cell[i].deactivate();
                }*/
                System.out.println(checkNeighbor(i));
            }
        }

        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("stop"))
        {
            //timer.stop();
            for(int i=0;i<=1124;i++)
            {
                if(cell[i].isActivated())
                    System.out.println(cell[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    public static int checkNeighbor(int c)
    {
        int neighbors = 0;
        if(c-46>0)
        {
            if(cell[c-46].isActivated()==true)
                neighbors++;
        }
        if(c-45>0)
        {
            if(cell[c-45].isActivated()==true)
                neighbors++;
        }
        if(c-44>0)
        {
            if(cell[c-44].isActivated()==true)
                neighbors++;
        }
        if(c-1>0)
        {
            if(cell[c-1].isActivated()==true)
                neighbors++;
        }
        if(c+1<1124)
        {
            if(cell[c+1].isActivated()==true)
                neighbors++;
        }
        if(c+44<1124)
        {
            if(cell[c+44].isActivated()==true)
                neighbors++;
        }
        if(c+45<1124)
        {
            if(cell[c+45].isActivated()==true)
                neighbors++;
        }
        if(c+46<1124)
        {
            if(cell[c+46].isActivated()==true)
                neighbors++;
        }
        return neighbors;
    }
}
```

End of mainGUI.java. What follows is mainCell.java:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainCell extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1761933778208900172L;

    private static boolean activated = false;

    public static int posX = 0;

    public static int posY = 0;

    public mainCell()
    {
        Dimension dim = new Dimension(15, 15);
        setPreferredSize(dim);
        setBackground(mainGUI.black);
        addMouseListener(this);
    }

    public void activate()
    {
        Color yellow = new Color(255,255,0);
        setBackground(yellow);
        System.out.println(getName()+" activated");
        setActivated(true);
    }

    public void deactivate()
    {
        setBackground(mainGUI.black);
        System.out.println(getName()+" deactivated");
        setActivated(false);
    }

    public void setPos(int x, int y)
    {
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)
    {

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0)
    {

    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0)
    {

    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0)
    {
        if(this.isActivated()==true)
        {
            this.deactivate();
        }
        else if(this.isActivated()==false)
        {
            this.activate();
        }
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0)
    {

    }

    public boolean isActivated()
    {
        return activated;
    }

    public static void setActivated(boolean activated)
    {
        mainCell.activated = activated;
    }

}
```

Like you may have guessed, it is a recreation of John Conway's Game of Life in Java. What happens, though, is when one "cell" or panel is activated, all the others have their variable "activated" set to true. Why is this? How can I keep this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class mainCell extends JPanel implements MouseListener
{

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 1761933778208900172L;

    private static boolean activated = false;  // **** should not be static ****

    public static int posX = 0;  // **** should not be static ****

    public static int posY = 0;  // **** should not be static ****
```

Remember: ***Don't use static variables needlessly***

Please understand that static variables are **class** variables, and so they are not unique to each instance of the class but instead shared by all instances. If you set one, you set it for all. Use instance variables whenever possible instead.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much! I had no idea, only a few weeks into my Java class and its my second big project. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: @mistapaluza: again, only make a variable static if it makes sense to be static. Solution: get rid of those statics. Your constant serialVersionUID *should* be static but all the other fields should not. Same for all those variables in your mainGUI (which should be renamed MainGui, and the other class renamed MainCell).

Comment: Alrighty then. I just tried it and recompiled, and things have gone "astray" again. Instead of functioning as it should, the entire thing activates.

Comment: @mistapaluza: then it's time to do some debugging.

Comment: Yeah! Haha, woops. Sorry, I thought it could've been some sort of error like the above but I think it may be the "rules" I set up. Thanks again!